# Importing @arcgis/core ElevationLayer and Point doubles build size

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

When using the `Point` and `ElevationLayer` from `@arcgis/core`, it doubles my bundle size up to 20MB with 127 files in a React build. Once, I remove the import, it drops down to just 9 files (including src map) and about 10MB.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
import Point from '@arcgis/core/geometry/Point'
import ElevationLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/ElevationLayer'
```

I use this to query a LatLng position for elevation.

I'm using `@arcgis/core` version `4.21.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is because bundling is working correctly. Files may be added to on-disk bundles increasing the on-disk footprint size, however that does not necessarily indicate they will be requested by the app at runtime. For example, we ran a quick test and those two imports only increase initial app load size by 150Kb - 200Kb.